# Why PyTest is not collecting tests (collected 0 items)?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I have been trying to run unit tests using [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/).

I wrote a module with one class and some methods inside that class, and I wrote a unit test for this module (with a simple assert statement to check equality of lists) where I first instantiated the class with a list.

Then I invoke a method on that object (from the class). Both `test.py` and the script to be tested are in the same folder. When I run `pytest` on it, it reports "collected 0 items".

I am new to `pytest` and but I am unable to run their examples successfully. What am I missing here?

I am running Python version 3.5.1 and pytest version 2.8.1 on Windows 7.

My *test.py* code:

```
from sort_algos import Sorts

def integer_sort_test():
    myobject1 = Sorts([-100, 10, -10])
    assert myobject1.merge_sort() == [-101, -100, 10]
```

`sort_algos.py` is a module containing `Sorts` class.

`merge_sort` is a method from `Sorts`.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. What would you expect as a result if you place an empty `.py` file?

Comment: Random memory - something about `.py` being skipped if it's executable - see if it is and either change it to non-executable, or see if `pytest` has a `include executable` option?

Comment: @ Zulan, added sample code to my post

Answer (score 180, accepted):

`pytest` gathers tests according to a naming convention.  By default any file that is to contain tests must be named starting with `test_`, classes that hold tests must be named starting with `Test`, and any function in a file that should be treated as a test must also start with `test_`.

If you rename your test file to `test_sorts.py` and rename the example function you provide above as `test_integer_sort`, then you will find it is automatically collected and executed.

This test collecting behavior [can be changed](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/example/pythoncollection.html) to suit your desires. Changing it will require learning about [configuration in pytest](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/customize.html).

Comment: thanks a lot !Yes, that worked. OMG, I never realized that !

Comment: Glad I was able to help.  Would you mind marking this as the correct answer?  Thanks!

Comment: Both links in this answer are now Error 404 :(

Comment: Was stuck even KNOWING the naming convention but was ignoring it. Great reminder. Thanks

Answer (score 19):

I had the same issue, but my function was called `test.py`. I never thought that the issue would be the file name.

In the documentation it says:

> pytest will run all files of the form `test_*.py` or `*_test.py` in the current directory and its subdirectories. More generally, it follows standard test discovery rules.

Exactly! The name should be `test_.py` or `test_something.py` and works for me.

I feel so stupid, hehe.

Answer (score 7):

I can't upvote yet but want to chime in with a combo solution that worked for me.

First, per above, I renamed my file with 'test_': `test_hello.py`.

Second, also per above, I renamed each bit I wanted to test with 'test_'

```py
def test_greeting():
    print('Hello, world!')

def test_checkout():
    print("This is checkout")

def logout():
    print("This is logout")

def test_executable():
    """says hello world by default"""
    out = getoutput({prg})
```

And finally, to actually run the test, I entered the following on the command line:

```sh
python -m pytest -v test_hello.py
```

Without the `-m` there is a message the file cannot be opened. It works without the `-v`, but with it, it breaks down each part being tested. RESULT:

```
---------------------------------------------
collected 3 items

test_hello.py::test_greeting PASSED                                                                              [ 33%]
test_hello.py::test_checkout PASSED                                                                              [ 66%]
test_hello.py::test_executable FAILED


def test_executable():
        """says hello world by default"""
>       out = getoutput({prg})
E       NameError: name 'getoutput' is not defined

test_hello.py:12: NameError
```

As you can see, it skipped `logout()`, the part of the program with no test_, and delivered a useful error message. So, with that simple example, things are running as they should. Thank you to everyone who helped me put it together.

Answer (score 3):

I faced this issue too and it took me a whole day to find out that the class name should start with "Test" my class name was "test" instead. That made me run my code successfully.

Make sure your python test file name and method name should also start with "test_"

Answer (score 2):

This helped me a lot. Initially I named my tests below:

```
def login():
    print("This is login")

def checkout():
    print("This is checkout")

def logout():
    print("This is logout")
```

My pytest command ran without errors. However, no results were produced. I also observed:

> collected 0 items

Hence I renamed the above tests to `test_login()`, `test_checkout()`, `test_logout()` and now I got successful results!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem as well. And it was *not* caused by script names, but due to a plugin called "pytest-appium" which I have no intention to use in the first place.

I finally found it out from report:
('c:\python39\lib\site-packages\pytest_appium\plugin.py', 8, 'Skipped: no variables file')

Since *plugin.py* requires variables which I have no idea what it is for.

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def appium(variables):
    if not variables:
        pytest.skip('no variables file')
```

Solution:

```
pip uninstall pytest-appium
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're still getting

> collected 0 items
>
> ======================= no tests ran in X.XXs======================

save your files again (in VSCode) to get files updated