# Running pytest.main(...) does not collect tests

Tags: python, python-2.7, testing, automation, pytest

I've created a sub folder with `test_*.py` files and additional `.py` files which hold additional methods which are being called.
In the root directory of the project I've created `main_test.py` in which I call `pytest.main(['./subdfolder'])`. `pytest` is being triggered but I'm getting the blow output:

```
============================= test session starts =============================
platform win32 -- Python 2.7.14, pytest-3.6.1, py-1.5.3, pluggy-0.6.0
rootdir: C:\PycharmProjects\TestingFramework, inifile:
plugins: tap-2.2, report-0.2.1
collected 0 items

======================== no tests ran in 0.01 seconds =========================
```

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Is `subdfolder` the correct dir name?

Comment: yes , one level above it sits the main_test.py where i try to call pytest.main()

Comment: Hmm, then you have to provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) because I can't reproduce the issue - maybe your test functions have an incorrect name, thus not being collected? Make sure the test function names start with `test_`. If you have test classes, make sure their names start with `Test`.

Comment: never mind , found the issue , basically i was trying to invoke main_test.py using the pytest invocation , when in fact i should have been calling the pytest.main() from the main_test.py which in turn should have been triggerted as regular python scriupt , silly me

Comment: Nice! Consider writing an answer explaining the issue so it might help others looking for a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Edited*
What I've discovered is that I've approached it all wrong the command: 
    *pytest.main()*
cannot be invoked from the terminal line (i'm using PyCharm) the correct approach is would be to place the all of the code inside of   *if **name** == "**main**"* block in the following manner :

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
   junit_path = '.\Reports\/Junit_' + time.strftime("%d%m%Y_%H%M%S") + '.xml'
   result_log_path = '.\Reports\/Logs\/Execution_' + 
   time.strftime("%d%m%Y_%H%M%S") + '.log'
   pytest.main(['-v', '-x','--junitxml', junit_path, '--resultlog', result_log_path])
```

after that using the terminal command line I was able to call the execution by calling:

```
python ./<<file name>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to rename the file to start with `test_`. In this case `main_test.py` most likely needs to be `test_main.py` (reversed).

I found the answer here: ['pytest' exits with no error, but with "collected 0 items"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37353960/pytest-exits-with-no-error-but-with-collected-0-items)