# Microsoft azure devops python pipeline fails with Bash exited with code '5'

Tags: python, git, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm following the tutorial at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/python?view=azure-devops.

Here is my azure-pipelines.yml file:

```
# Python package
# Create and test a Python package on multiple Python versions.
# Add steps that analyze code, save the dist with the build record, publish to a PyPI-compatible index, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/python

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
strategy:
  matrix:
    Python27:
      python.version: '2.7'
    Python35:
      python.version: '3.5'
    Python36:
      python.version: '3.6'
    Python37:
      python.version: '3.7'

steps:
- task: UsePythonVersion@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '$(python.version)'
  displayName: 'Use Python $(python.version)'

- script: |
    python -m pip install --upgrade pip
    pip install -r requirements.txt
  displayName: 'Install dependencies'

- script: |
    pip install pytest pytest-azurepipelines
    pytest
  displayName: 'pytest'
```

Running the pipeline fails with the following error message.

> Bash exited with code '5'.

I enabled system diagnostics to add debug messages to the log.

The error occurs in the pytest phase of the pipeline.
[image]

The full log is available at https://github.com/michaelhochleitner/debug-azure-devops-python-pipeline/blob/master/log.txt.

How can I make the pipeline run without failing?

Comment: `pytest` reported *collected 0 items*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I make the pipeline run without failing?

Agree with **phd**, the issue comes cause **0** test items can be collected.

Check [this detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37367040/10910450) from **cewing**:

*Pytest gathers tests according to a naming convention. By default any file that is to contain tests must be named starting with test_ and any function in a file that should be treated as a test must also start with test_.*

So it's obvious that pytest command can't find any `xx.py` file whose name starts with `test_`. So for pytest, there's no available tests for it and this causes the `0 items collected`=>`Bash exited with code '5'`.

I checked your tutorial above and reproduce same issue:

[image]

**To resolve it and make the run succeed:**

For me, I simply created a new `test_anyname.py` file with content(`test_xx.py`+`test_xx method`) below:

[image]

And my pipeline then run successfully without `Bash exited with code '5'`:

[image]

So you should make sure at least one test item can be found, and the error would go away. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks for identifying the problem. It's fixed in the sample repo now thanks to a community PR.

Comment: This worked in my instance as well, great explanation, thanks! @KraigBrockschmidt-MSFT - what would be required to update the originally linked tutorial? I notice it hasn't been updated since initial publish in Nov 2019, pretty frustrating to say the least.